# R circular LOESS function over 24 hours (a day)

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, loess

I have data for free parking slots over hours and days.

Here's a random sample of 100.

```
sl <- list(EmptySlots = c(7, 6, 20, 5, 16, 20, 24, 5, 24, 24, 15, 11, 
8, 6, 13, 2, 21, 6, 1, 6, 9, 1, 8, 0, 20, 9, 20, 11, 22, 24, 
1, 2, 12, 6, 8, 2, 23, 18, 8, 3, 20, 2, 1, 0, 5, 21, 1, 4, 20, 
15, 24, 12, 4, 14, 2, 4, 20, 16, 2, 10, 2, 1, 24, 9, 22, 7, 6, 
3, 20, 13, 1, 16, 12, 5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 0, 13, 24, 6, 
13, 7, 24, 24, 15, 6, 10, 1, 2, 9, 5, 2, 11, 15), hour = c(8, 
16, 23, 14, 18, 7, 17, 15, 19, 19, 17, 17, 16, 14, 17, 12, 19, 
10, 10, 13, 16, 10, 16, 11, 12, 9, 0, 15, 16, 21, 10, 11, 17, 
11, 16, 15, 23, 7, 16, 14, 18, 14, 14, 9, 15, 2, 10, 9, 19, 17, 
20, 16, 12, 17, 12, 9, 23, 9, 15, 17, 10, 12, 18, 17, 18, 17, 
13, 10, 7, 8, 10, 18, 11, 11, 12, 17, 12, 9, 14, 15, 10, 11, 
10, 10, 20, 16, 18, 15, 21, 18, 17, 13, 8, 11, 15, 16, 11, 9, 
12, 18))
```

A quick way to calculate a LOESS function via `ggplot2`.

```
sl <- as.data.frame(sl)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(hour, EmptySlots, data=sl, geom="jitter") + theme_bw() + stat_smooth(size = 2)
```

[image]
*What is the best way to tell the LOESS function that 0 and 24 are neighbours?* I.e. the line on the left and the right should be the same value if we were to estimate it this way.

Pointers on where to start will do fine.

Comment: Duplicated your data on either side, so you have three copies. Then only keep the portion fit to the middle piece.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd be tempted just to replicate the data on either side:

```
library(ggplot2)
empty <- c(7, 6, 20, 5, 16, 20, 24, 5, 24, 24, 15, 11, 8, 6, 13, 2, 21, 6, 1, 6, 9, 1, 8, 0, 20, 9, 20, 11, 22, 24, 1, 2, 12, 6, 8, 2, 23, 18, 8, 3, 20, 2, 1, 0, 5, 21, 1, 4, 20, 15, 24, 12, 4, 14, 2, 4, 20, 16, 2, 10, 2, 1, 24, 9, 22, 7, 6, 3, 20, 13, 1, 16, 12, 5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 0, 13, 24, 6, 13, 7, 24, 24, 15, 6, 10, 1, 2, 9, 5, 2, 11, 15)
hour <- c(8, 16, 23, 14, 18, 7, 17, 15, 19, 19, 17, 17, 16, 14, 17, 12, 19, 10, 10, 13, 16, 10, 16, 11, 12, 9, 0, 15, 16, 21, 10, 11, 17, 11, 16, 15, 23, 7, 16, 14, 18, 14, 14, 9, 15, 2, 10, 9, 19, 17, 20, 16, 12, 17, 12, 9, 23, 9, 15, 17, 10, 12, 18, 17, 18, 17, 13, 10, 7, 8, 10, 18, 11, 11, 12, 17, 12, 9, 14, 15, 10, 11, 10, 10, 20, 16, 18, 15, 21, 18, 17, 13, 8, 11, 15, 16, 11, 9, 12, 18)
emptyrep <- rep.int(empty,3)
hourrep <- c(hour,hour+24,hour-24)
sl <- data.frame(empty=emptyrep, hour=hourrep)
qplot(hour, empty, data=sl, geom="jitter") + theme_bw() + geom_smooth(method="loess",size = 1.5,span=0.2) +  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,24))
```

[image]

... just like joran said a few minutes earlier (woops)

Comment: That seems like the easiest solution. I suppose efficiency (not duplicating your data) is not important in the age of cheap computing.

Comment: If you had a million points this would definitely be wasteful.  You can do better by only replicating the points that "matter" -- that fall within the span used by loess.  But if you're using default values and it bootstraps that span, you don't know what the relevant spans are a priori.   The alternative is to use a computational method that does this automatically (you could look at periodic.lowess in princurve for something you'd have to transform your data to use), but that trades off memory efficiency for much higher compute time -- a pretty common tradeoff.